# Determine Correct PropertyName for PropertyChanged Event

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to figure out how to determine exactly what property name should be used in a PropertyChanged event for the Text property of the TextBlock below.

```
                    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding PrimitiveNodes}">
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding PrimitiveNodes}">
                                <TextBlock PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ContextMenu="{StaticResource TreeViewItemContextMenu}" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
                                           Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
```

And Here is the code I am using for the Text property.

```
// Called out in the Name property when it is set
this.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.TextProperty.Name);
```

Here is the OnPropertyChanged function

```
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Both the *IsSelected* and *IsExpanded* properties update correctly when changed from the code behind.  The *Text* property, however, does not.  I tried passing **null** to *OnPropertyChanged* when the *Name* property was updated (thus forcing all properties to update) and that worked fine, the *Text* property of the *TextBlock* was correctly updated with the new value.  So I suspect that maybe I'm passing the wrong string as a *propertyName* for the *Text* property of the *TextBlock* when it is updated, but I'm not sure what the correct property name should be or how I would go about figuring it out.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: when the "Name" Property is changed, the propertyName of the PropertyChangedEventArg should be... well... "Name" :-) it is the purpose of Binding to 'forget' where the property might be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it `"Name"`, since the name of the property that is getting changed is called `Name`

```
this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
```

By raising the PropertyChanged event on the `Name` property, you are telling WPF that the property has changed so update any bindings that use that property.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is meant to be used in with Data Models, not UI objects. Ideally, it shouldn't ever reference UI controls.

The reason why `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` work using the property name is because the property name is the same in both the UI object and the data object. This is a horrible way of raising PropertyChanged notifications, so I would suggest switching to passing it the actual Property Name, not some property name of a UI object.

Comment: If you have time, would you mind providing a small example of how your suggestion would be implemented?  Or maybe you know of a good link I could read up on?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Craig You mean the `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded` property change notifications? That's the same as the `Name` one, but replace the string with whatever property name has changed. `this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");` You can see examples at the [MSDN site for `INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: Ahh are you referring to my use of System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.TextProperty.Name in the OnPropertyChanged event?  Sorry I put that in there in one of my attempts to make it work, originally I had the string "Text" in there and for the IsSelected/IsExpanded I do actually use a string literal "IsSelected" and "IsExpanded".  I thought I was notifying the UI properties that their binding had updated, but actually I'm notifying all UI properties which bind the data property that it has changed, which makes much more sense now that I think about it.  Thanks a lot!